# Allowed latest update. System froze. Reboot to contiuous login loop and what do you mean?

Tags: grub2, login

Yesterday it said there was an update available, and would I like to install it. Since previously I had issues and an update corrected them, I figured this would help fix the quirky idiosyncrasies and freezes we were experiencing. Wrong. It froze the installation at a prompt to allow Windows fonts. I couldn't select "OK", and I couldn't cancel the install. Everything else was still working, but I couldn't get rid of that update window. I finally decide to power down, but it would not. You could select it from the menu, then you could select power down from the log-out option, but in no instance would it power down. It only kept repeating the cycle. I finally select log-out, which only brought me to the log-in screen, which would not allow me to log in. I powered it down by holding the power button  and re-booted. I am now in perpetual log-in loop. I cannot even log in as guest.

I searched "Ubuntu continuous log-in loop" on my XP desktop and began reading results. This is when I find that every remedy is geared to those familiar with Ubuntu. Each one requires typing a line of code in SOMEWHERE. What good is telling someone to type a line of code without telling them how to get where you are supposed to type it in?

"In the grub menu". GRUB menu? What the heck is a grub menu? If I find a grub I feed it to my chickens!

"Look at your dmxp" (Or some such thing. I can't remember now) What the heck is that? Where do I find it? When I do, what the heck am I looking for?

"Look at the logs and xsession errors"  ????????!!!!

There are several more such recommendations, all of which have absolutely no meaning to someone who just came on the scene. I was, however, able to glean a few things along the path. First, if you hold the shift key while booting, it will come to GNU GRUB (2.02~beta 2-9ubuntu1.4) I now have 4 options, NONE of which were ever discussed in any of the remedies. I found that if I go to "Advanced Options" I can go into recovery mode. (Which was mentioned in one remedy, but never how to get there!) OK, Recovery mode does not work, so the rest of that remedy is moot. Recovery does not work, period.

PLUS, nobody ever mentioned anywhere at any time about selecting `e`' to edit the commands before booting or `c` for a command line". Which one do I need, and what do I do when I get there?

THEN  I find <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>f1</kbd> somewhere in the quagmire of fixes. AH! This must be where they say to type in the selected codes! What the heck is `sudo`? Why does it tell me that the line I tired has to be entered manually?

I have now spent more time trying to repair and get this laptop working than I have in actual use. Does it get better from here? All I want to do is get out of continuous log-in loop and have a stable, operating machine.

Do you think that I need to be lead by the hand down the file path of repair? Let me tell you most assuredly, YES!!!!

PLEASE when you give an answer on these forums, give each step, and possibly some explanation of what is happening in said step. I want to understand just what it is I am doing, or about to do.

Do NOT tell me that I need to do a complete install and lose all of the email my wife has saved. If you do, then YOU come HERE and tell her yourself! SURELY there has to be a remedy somewhere to at least get back in, get the emails backed up or off, and then re-install.

Comment: Ok! Calm down first and then please edit your answer by sharing a picture or video of the login loop. Also, by login loop did you mean, it gets to the screen where you enter your password and it restarts or is your password not accepted?

Comment: @Raphael you look confused after reading his question ;) He has not posted any "answer" yet.

Answer (score 0):

ha, ha. Question of the day.

I'll give you a possible tip on how to get the emails.

If the /home directory is not encrypted, boot up a live session. This means starting the operating system from a DVD or USB. There you will see the disk with the installed instance of Ubuntu. Enter the /home directory and then the directory of your wife. There you will have to tell the file browser to show you hidden files. In the image below it's at the bottom of the menu with the down arrow.

[image]

Depending on what e-mail client your wifes' using, the mails will be at:

- default - .local/share/evolution/mail (This means you need to enter the directory ".local", then "share", and so on).
- thunderbird - .thunderbird - and then it may be in different places and you may need to look for it, but by dafault it will be in a directory with a name ending in ".default", then "Mail", possibly also "ImapMail" if she uses the IMAP protocol.
- some other client - .someOtherClient - and then an appropriate subdirectory path

From her home directory you she may also want some other things like photos, music, documents, etc. Good news is that if the system was not configured by a creative IT genius, everything should be in her home subdirectory. I strongly advise you backup the whole home directory, ie. the one which has the name of your wife.

Now, if the /home directory is encrypted, you should be able to enter it from a live session (same as with me first tip for non-encrypted one) after entering the encryption password, which most likely is the root password of the Ubuntu instance, if the /home directory was created at the same time. If you have problems with that, you'll surely come back with feedback.

That's all the tips I can give you. I hope they help. But first of all, I hope you manage to fix your Ubuntu.